# Run Firebase app on Mobile phone results shows successful but app icon does not appear on the list

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have this simple firebase app to send message to the firebasedatabase, when i  run in my mobile phone, android  show run successful with no logcat error, also  the bad thing is app icon doesn't  appear on the mobile phone icon list. But when i test" hellow world" app in android studion it work fine..
 so far i have added internet permission and adding dependencies fine.

Any help  please

here is my code

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  Button myButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Write a message to the database
            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
            myRef.setValue(" This is My Message!"); 
        }
    });
}
}
```

and this is what come after run

```
Executing external task 'signingReport'...
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:signingReport
Variant: debug
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\....path ....\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: ***********// MD5 contents
SHA1: ***********//sha1 contents
Valid until: Wednesday, November 14, 2046
```

Comment: What do you mean by "app icon doesn't appear on the list"?

Comment: There are a lot of things that could be going on, but one likely one is that you're not allowed to write the data. To detect that in your code, see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/19721/detect-errors-when-writing-a-value-on-android#t=201611261611269199286

Comment: when i test an app in mobile phone it has to launch and  it icon  has to appear phone icons list but on my case non of them appear @Raghav

Comment: thanks for your advice but still does not work@Frank van Puffelen

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you've followed all steps of Firebase integration in the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Make sure you have permissions for INTERNET and also recommended to add WRITE_EXTERNAT_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAT_STORAGE. Also, check the permissions on your mobile phone - especially if it's Android 6.0 you might need to accept the permissions manually in your settings menu.

If the app icon doesn't appear on your mobile phone, there might be some compatibility problems with the device. I'd suggest first trying to install the app on a couple of other devices to see if it's the problem of the device or the software connection. Also, check your minimum API level - does it match your devices Android version.

Comment: Thanks for you respond, the problem is that does not build apk , also does not open window to chose running on device or emulator @serj Ardovic

Comment: when button clicked it bring this message :Executing external task 'signingReport'...
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:signingReport
Variant: debug
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\....path ....\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: ***********// MD5 contents
SHA1: ***********//sha1 contents
Valid until: Wednesday, November 14, 2046 @ ser Ardovic

Comment: it's normal - no problem there. You could try to build a debug .apk (or even signed .apk), put it into your phone storage and manually install - see what happens.

Comment: APK does not get built @serj Ardovic

Answer (score 0):

Add below line to your Main Activty

```
<intent-filter>
//Main(like First Activity to run when you press app Icon from Launcher)
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
//Launcher(to add launcher..If you don't add this your icon will not be visible in launcher)
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: everything is ok, but  when i click the run button does not even "select  deployment  target  " window does not show up  and i realized that apk does not get build. Am using 2.3 android studio  @Raghavendra B

Answer (score 0):

I had also this problem and solution is on left side of run button there is an android icon press it drop down will show and select app